# Docusign send documents to sign to our clients via our plateform

Tags: docusignapi

I studied the different authentication methods and i found that the JWT grant method is the best suited for our plateform. We need to send envelope to our clients which will subscribe to our website with any email from any domain. We purchase the plan : basic api plan, Site: NA3-EU1.

```
example 1:
our domain is for example : domain-a.com
sender : hello@domain-a.com
receiver : martin@gmail.com
example 2 :
sender: hello@domain-a.com
receiver:jean@domain-b.us
```

our goal is to be able to send automatically, when registering our client "martin@gmail.com" in our platform an email to sign documents. Once signed by martin@gmail.com ... we download the signed document.

Is the JWT grant flow is the best method for our case ? Please if possible provide an example.

Comment: Answered below. If it helped you out, be sure to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. It sounds like you don't need to have individual users authenticate themselves, so JWT grant flow is the right way to go.

After reviewing this [authentication guide on JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken), you should check out the language-specific code examples linked on that page.

Now, on to your use case... It looks to me like your clients will receive a very similar `template`. With Docusign, you can create a template of documents, roles, and tabs and send that template to each new client.

Here's an example that demonstrates how to create and send an envelope that contains a template. The template is set up to expect two recipients, one signer and one carbon copy. There is also a "note" tab assigned to the signer, which I've prepopulated with his `physicalAddress`

```
POST /envelopes 
    {
        "status": "sent",
        "templateId": "00df08bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ecaa2360c121",
        "templateRoles": [
            {
                "email": "test@test.com",
                "name": "Test User",
                "roleName": "signer",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "note": [
                        {
                            "tabLabel": "physicalAddress",
                            "value": "221 Main St. San Francisco, CA"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "email": "test2@test.com",
                "name": "Another user",
                "roleName": "cc",
                "routingOrder": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
```